# nodejs express app.get restrict for specific url

Tags: node.js, security, express, get, restriction

I'm thinking of relatibly easy actions to make my node.js server more secure and i thought of restricting the app.get calls to only one url (the website hosted in another hosting). Is this possible?

I did not find such a thing on the net.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean? The backend server on the other host is calling your API or is the call coming from the frontend (from a site hosted on the other host)? The latter is easily spoofable but the former you could check the `req.remoteAddress` as long as the IP is static.

Comment: yes i was talking about the frontend, your comment could help me thanks